# How to get simulator(.exe) path from dll in C

Tags: c, dll, exe

I have to get which exe use my dll at the moment. How to accomplish it from dll?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it work? How didn't it work? I also suggest you try to search for a way to get the *module handle* of the exe file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLLs are Windows shared object files, I assume you use C with the windows SDK and windows.h is available for you to include.

In that case, use the GetModuleFileName() function. Use 0 as the module handle and you'll get the executable name.

```
wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH]; 
GetModuleFileName(0, buffer, MAX_PATH);
```

Comment: Since `GetModuleFileName()` could take either `char*` or `wchar_t*`, I'd recommend either using a `TCHAR` buffer, *or* `GetModuleFileNameW()`.